# Insert Data Into Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, iteration

I have a table with multiple rows of data(sku, start day, end day). I am wanting to iterate through the table and insert its data into pre-existing Excel file. The problem is my Excel file does not have headers(The entire first row is merged. I have my connection string built, but I am at a dead end on how to insert data with the Excel file not having the proper headers

```
if (skuQuery != null)
{
    String Model = skuQuery.Model;
    String skuHTML = skuQuery.skuHTML;
    String fileExtension = ".xls";
    String connString = "";
    String fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/PropertyRoom/" + "PRTemplate-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".xls");
    //Check whether file extension is xls or xslx

    if (fileExtension == ".xls") { connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\""; }
    else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx") { connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\""; }
}
else { continue; }
```

Note: the Excel output must be in the Excel 97-2003 format.

Answer (score 2):

```
   using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(fileLocation))
    {
      ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Accounts");
      ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);
      pck.Save();
    }
```

I would recommend EPPlus (http://epplus.codeplex.com/). Its available on nuget.

Comment: Using EPPlus is not an option. The output excel file need sot be compatible with an outside system which i have no control over.  the Excel file must be .xls(97-2003) otherwise it will not be accepted

Comment: This library looks similar and supports xls by the looks http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/